# Cannot read property 'params' of undefined React Ntiave

Tags: react-native

I can't use React Native params
I want to get data to pass to the bottomSheet

```
const ProductOption = ({

  handleClosePress,
  route,
}) => {
  const {product} = route.params;
  return (
    <BottomSheet
      index={-1}
      backgroundStyle={{backgroundColor: colors.bodyColor}}
      <BottomSheetView>
....
```

ProductItem

```
 <TouchableOpacity
                    
                    onPress={() => {
                      handleSnapPress(0), {product: item};
                    }}>
```

Comment: Please add a min git or expo example so we can test it

Comment: have you logged your **product** ..?

Comment: github: https://github.com/khuongviettai/CoffeeApp